# Changing svg fill colors

Tags: jquery, svg

For some days i am trying to make a function (with no luck) that creates a shield using combination of a .png and an .svg images. My goal is to create several images changing .svg pattern colors.

First attempts was, using the {img} tag to achieve that. Then i figured out that  can't happens using {img}. So i tried the {object} tag..

This is the style of my svg image, .st0{fill:#F3082F;}.st1{fill:#0A48F2;} and like to change it to st0= #fff, st1=#000

What i' ve done:

```
body { background-color:#282828;}
#tbl {display: table;margin:0 0 0 540px;}
.tbl-row {display: table-row;}
.shield {display: table-cell;}

<br>
<div style="position: absolute;"></div>
<div id="tbl" style="position: absolute;"> 
    <div class="tbl-row">
        <div class="myshield" style="margin-left:0px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then this function created:

```
function drawshield(elmClass, shield, shieldPattern, shieldPatternAColor, shieldPatternBColor) {
    var Shield = '<div class="shieldContainer" style="position:relative;width:230px;height:269px;">'+
        '<div class="shieldImage" style="position: absolute;">';    

    // Add shield image
    Shield += '<img src="http://imgh.us/'+shield+'.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:100;">';
    // Add emblem pattern
var svgpath = 'http://imgh.us/'+shield+'-'+shieldPattern+'.svg';
    Shield += '<object id="myShieldObj" data="'+svgpath+'" type="image/svg+xml" height="269px" width="229px"></object>';
/* What code i must use here to change style colors ? */        
    Shield += ' </div>'+
    '</div>';
    $("." + elmClass).append(Shield);
```

}

And call **drawshield**('myshield', 'shield-1', 'pattern-1', 'fff', '000'); to create the image.

The problem is that not any colors change happened... Image displayed with his own colors and not the new one. I tried many things but nothing works.
Is there anyway to add svg as inline code (like the php file_get_contents("xxxxx.svg")) and then change **Shield** var fill colors using some string functions? or is there any other way to do this within function?

I tested this code too but does seems to work either.

```
$("#myShieldObj"). load (function () {
      $("#myShieldObj").find(".st0").css({ fill: '#fff' });
      $("#myShieldObj").find(".st1").css({ fill: '#000' });
});
```

Samlpe code exists in [codepen](http://codepen.io/snart1/pen/amwPbJ)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to try to use `<image>` tags inside the `svg` - cf [SVG image element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag). This would probably be more convenient.

Comment: try the following: `$("#myShieldObj"). load (function () {
console.log('loaded') })`.
 `load` is never called. `ready` works, however it seems it still does not give access to `$('#myShieldObj')[0].contentDocument` (cf. https://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/)

Comment: that what i ask in "Is there anyway to add svg as inline code (like the php file_get_contents("xxxxx.svg")) and then change Shield var fill colors using some string functions?" Mehdi....

Comment: Yes i figured out too..